# Highcharts: maximum height of chart doesnt exeeds 1000px

Tags: highcharts

Is the maximum height chart limited to 1000px?

i can't seem to make it take full length of my screen

[image]

There is always this empty space left below the chart on bigger screens.

Comment: Hi @user4772933, Could you reproduce that issue in some online code editor? In a basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/83k1g5hx/ everything seems to work.

Comment: You are right .. thanks .. it works .. something was wrong with my css your fiddle example helped me debug.. thanks again